# Preventing Chromium window from coming to foreground when connecting through CDP

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I am connecting to a local Chromium process through CDP.

```ts
const browser = await playwright.chromium.connectOverCDP(cdpUrl);
const defaultContext = browser.contexts()[0];
const page = await defaultContext.newPage();
```

The page creation brings the Chromium window to the foreground. Is it possible to prevent this ?

I have tried looking up for documentation related to this but wasn't able to find any useful information.

Comment: Aside: `newPage()` returns a promise so you should `await` it. All variables should be declared `const` so they're block scoped rather than globals.